# Why does PyTorch's Linear layer store the weight in shape (out, in) and transpose it in the forward pass?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

PyTorch's `Linear` layer stores the `weight` attribute in the shape `(out_features, in_features)`. In the forward pass, the following operation is performed:

```py
def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
```

which is equivalent to:

```py
def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    return torch.addmm(self.bias, input, self.weight.t())
```

This is strange. Why isn't the `weight` attribute stored in the shape of `(in_features, out_features)`, eliminating the need for a transposition in the forward and backward pass?

I performed a benchmark to compare both storage methods (forward and backward pass over 10,000 iterations) and found that a pre-transposed weight was around 10µs faster per iteration. The benchmark used a tensor with 100 features and 128 rows of random data. To ensure fairness, both `Linear` layers were configured with the same parameters, including the weight and bias, and were applied to identical random data.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of storing weights in the shape (out_features, in_features) in PyTorch's Linear layer and transposing during the forward pass is a matter of convention and consistency within the library.

In mathematical notation, a typical linear transformation is represented as (y = Wx + b), where (W) is of shape (out_features, in_features). By using this convention, PyTorch maintains consistency with other linear algebra routines and typical mathematical notation. This choice allows for a more intuitive understanding for those who are familiar with the mathematical formulation of linear transformations.

The transposition overhead you observed in your benchmark is generally minimal and would usually be overshadowed by other computational costs in most real-world scenarios. While you did notice a difference in your micro-benchmark, in practice, the design choice's impact on overall performance is usually negligible.

In TensorFlow, the convention for the weight matrix in a dense (fully connected) layer is the opposite of PyTorch. The weight matrix is defined with the shape (in_features, out_features), aligning with the operation (y = xW + b). This is consistent with TensorFlow's internal design and the way matrix multiplications are handled within the framework.

The difference between PyTorch and TensorFlow in this aspect illustrates that these conventions are library-specific and can vary based on design choices made by the developers. While they might result in slight differences in performance or implementation, both approaches are valid and align with the respective library's internal logic and other operations.